# How can I attach the file in send email?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

I want to send an email attaching a file from the FTP folder.
I have set up an automation that includes several steps
SQLactivity- data Extract- transfer activity - Send email.

How can I attach the file in send email?

Comment: Hi Mary, this and few other of your questions can be easily answered by searching the historical questions here on SFSE. Does this answer your question? [Dynamically send Attachment from Marketing Cloud](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/319860/dynamically-send-attachment-from-marketing-cloud)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email Attachments need to be activated by Salesforce Support.
If that has been done you need to add an Ampscript function to the Email as described in the documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/attachfile.htm

Edit: Since the answer was marked correct, let me insert the hint from the comments here, that this is a **paid feature**.

Comment: This is a paid feature. You would need to reach out to your account team

Comment: With my last client I was told it uses up more supermessages, if I am not mistaken. But maybe there are different options.

Comment: @donl it does not count as supermessages, but you buy attachments in bulk (e.g. 10.000) and hence it uses these instead of supermessages. One email with attachment will then use 1 supermessage + 1 attachment